# Create quicktabs programmatically drupal

Tags: drupal, tabs, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 & quicktab . I am trying to create quicktabs from codes.
Suppose i created the a test url in using hook menu.

```
$items['MyModule/test'] = array(
        'title' => 'Test Tabs',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'test',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access arguments' => array('access content')

    );
```

In test function ,

```
function test(){

    $name = "Test tabs";
    $settings = array(
        'ajax' => 0 ,
        'hide_if_empty' => 1,
        'default_tab' => 0,
        'title' => 'Test quicktabs',
        'rendered' => 'quicktabs',
        'style' => 'Basic',
    );
    $custom_tabs = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Test tab1',
            'path' => 'test-tab1',
            'contents' => "Test tab1",
            'weight' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Test tab2',
            'path' => 'test-tab2',

            'contents' => "Test tab2",
            'weight' => 0
        ));
return drupal_render(quicktabs_build_quicktabs($name, $settings, $custom_tabs));
}
```

By using above code , i am successfully able to create quicktabs,  But It is showing same (Test tab 1) content on both tabs. Content is not changing. I cleared the cache also. 
Also, How to edit the path of tabs?? Above path is not working . It is showing  ugly path like this `(http:[baseUrl]/test?qt-my_custom_quicktab=3&qt-Test%20tabs=0#qt-Test%20tabs)`

Is there any better way to implement quicktabs.May be with hooks but documentation is insufficient.  If anyone knows better implementation guide me . My tabs will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just the ugly query string `?qt-my_custom_quicktab=...`, you can prevent that using javascript by disabling the default click action for the links that toggle tab-panels.

Example:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#your-quicktab-link-selector').click(function(evn) {
        evn.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I figured I'd answer for anyone else who stumbled upon the same issue (as I did).

The problem is that your variable $name (or the first parameter to quicktabs_build_quicktabs()) should not have spaces. So, if you do something like the following, it will work.

```
$name = "Test-tabs";
```

The issue is that quicktabs assigns that string as part of the ID of the div wrapper on the tab. If it has a space in it, then the javascript code won't successfully hide or show the correct tabs.